# MSP430 I2C read multiple bytes communication problem

Tags: c, i2c, msp430

I'm trying to use a temperature sensor(PCT2075) by MSP430F249

To get a temperature, I get a 2bytes from this sensor.

I wrote a code from this link.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/589712?MSP430FR5969-Read-multiple-bytes-of-data-i2c-with-repeated-start-and-without-interrupts

I'm using MSP430F249. so I modified  a code from this link.

[image]
Howerver, I got just two same value. I think that it is MSByte.

Is there any way to get 2bytes from sensor.

[image]

my code here

```
void i2c_read_multi(uint8_t slv_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t l, uint8_t *arr)
{
   uint8_t i;

   while(UCB0STAT & UCBBUSY);

   UCB0I2CSA = slv_addr;                   // set slave address

   UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR | UCTXSTT;            // transmitter mode and START condition.

   while(UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);

   UCB0TXBUF = reg_addr;

   while(!(UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT));

   UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;                     // receiver mode

   UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;                   // START condition

   while(UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);             // make sure start has been cleared

   for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {

   while(!(IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG));

   if(i == l - 1){

       UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;           // STOP condition

   }

      arr[i] = UCB0RXBUF;

 }

   while(UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues ...

The linked to code assumes that the port only needs to read *one* byte for each output value.

But, based on the sensor documentation you've shown, for each value *output* to the array, we need to read *two* bytes (one for MSB and one for LSB).

And, we need to merge those two byte values into one 16 bit value. Note that `arr` is now `uint16_t` instead of `uint8_t`. And, `l` is now the number of [16 bit] *samples* (vs. number of *bytes*). So, the caller of this may need to be adjusted accordingly.

Further, note that we have to "ignore" the lower 5 bits of `lsb`. We do that by shifting the 16 bit value right by 5 bits (e.g. `val16 >>= 5`). I assume that's the correct way to do it. Or, it *could* be just `val16 &= ~0x1F` [less likely]. You may have to experiment a bit.

Here's the refactored code.

Note that this assumes the data arrives in "big endian" order [based on my best guess]. If it's actually little endian, reverse the `msb =` and `lsb =` statements.

Also, the placement of the "STOP" condition code may need to be adjusted. I had to guess as to whether it should be placed above the LSB read or MSB read.

I chose LSB--the last byte because that's closest to how the linked general i2c read is done. (i.e.) i2c doesn't know about or care about the MSB/LSB multiplexing of the device in question. It wants the STOP just before the last *byte* [*not* the 16 bit *sample*].

```
void
i2c_read_multi(uint8_t slv_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t l,
    uint16_t *arr)
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t msb;
    uint8_t lsb;
    uint16_t val16;

    while (UCB0STAT & UCBBUSY);

    // set slave address
    UCB0I2CSA = slv_addr;

    // transmitter mode and START condition.
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR | UCTXSTT;

    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);

    UCB0TXBUF = reg_addr;

    while (!(UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT));

    // receiver mode
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;

    // START condition
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;

    // make sure start has been cleared
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        while (!(IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG));
        msb = UCB0RXBUF;

        while (!(IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG));

        // STOP condition
        if (i == l - 1) {
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
        }

        lsb = UCB0RXBUF;

        val16 = msb;
        val16 <<= 8;
        val16 |= lsb;

        // use only most 11 significant bits
        // NOTE: this _may_ not be the correct way to scale the data
        val16 >>= 5;

        arr[i] = val16;
    }

    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. It is working perfectly. I realized how to get multiple bytes from I2C.